# Ruby: Dialog Boxes on Particular Screens

Tags: ruby, dialog, monitor, multiple-monitors

Currently working with / developing for / supporting a multi-platform
application that uses Ruby in the front-end. The application is
regularly used on systems with multiple monitors, as many as five in the
usual cases. On Windows machines, when our application opens up a dialog
box, it has the habit of opening the dialog box on the "first" screen,
even if the application is running on another screen.

Is there a way to a) obtain information on which screen the application
is currently running off of and b) force the dialog box to open on the
same screen? Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

edit: using gtk2

Comment: What framework or library are you using to open the dialog box?